# How to interpolate independent variable over five-year period?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation, panel-data, interpolation

I have panel data on income and population for the years 1990, 1995, 2000 and 2005. I would like to interpolate these two variables (both independent variables), so that I have data for every year between 1990 and 2005. I would like to ask whether linear or quadratic spline interpolation or another method would be most appropriate to do this?

I know that the interpolation does not produce real data but only estimates. What would be the problems I would have to address if I would use these interpolated data in a panel regression estimated by maximum likelihood (for example serial autocorrelation)?

In the case of serial autocorrelation the regression coefficients would not be affected but the t-values and the significance, is that right?

Comment: In addition to auto-correlation, if you use an interpolation method for both the variables, that would cause multi-collinearity. If you use an appropriate methods for panel regression, you need not worry about auto correlation, because it would be automatically taken care of, example error would be ARMA. I would be more concerned about multicollinearity.

Comment: I think multi-collinearity would only be a problem if I would use one variable to interpolate the other one. However, the initial idea was to use, for example, the data point 1990 and 1995 for income to interpolate data points for income for the years between 1990 and 1995. I planned to do the same for the population variable.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: You can't use the interpolated data in regression if these two variables are the only variables. The reason is that if these were the only variables, then by interpolating you would artificially inflate the sample size.

When there are other variables, it's not as clear cut. One issue with interpolation is that in economic data there's often a random walk-like element: as you know when step size decreases the variance of a random walk decreases proportionally to the step size. When you interpolate, the standard deviation, not the variance, is scaled linearly. In other words, if you had annual data, it would have been more noisy than it would using linear or similar interpolation. So, you're messing up the error structure of the model. I don't think that this is always a big issue, so interpolation may be OK.

I think the preferred approach is to build a model based explicitly on the 5 year frequency of the dependent variables.

Comment: I include more than these two variables in my regression, but for theoretical reasons I don't wanna drop these two. I found papers where researchers either used the 1990 data for the whole five-year period from 1990 to 1995 or they "applied linear interpolation to fill in data for missing years."